# MongoDB $addToSet adds an object again with different key sort

Tags: mongodb

When using `$addToSet`, if I run this twice, it's entering duplicate objects, but with the `name` and `key` in reverse order.  Is there anyway to have this avoid this, so that it will only add one time?

```
var categories = [{
  name: 'One',
  key: 'one'
}]

User.update({_id : id}, {$addToSet : {'items' : {$each : categories }}});
```

Comment: What is the value of id? Is this changing each time? Try setting it to a constant. Does it have the same effect?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same, literally 'one' as a string.  The same two objects are in the items array, just with name/key 'keys' in reverse order.

Comment: So your update function evaluates to User.update({_id : 'one'}, {$addToSet : {'items' : {$each : categories }}}); ?

Comment: ah, sorry no id is an objectid, it's the same each time.  It's updating the right collection.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `$addToSet` matches with object exactly including the order of the attributes. The `$addToSet` operator is unable to recognize if the attributes are in arbitrary order (as mentioned in OP).

However, the `$elemMatch` works fine when the order of the attributes are not same (i.e. it can find that the embedded document is already available in the array). So, the workaround solution would be to use  `$elemMatch` with `$not` to check the existence of the values in array and update if not present.

```
var categories = [{
key: 'one',  
    name: 'One'
}]
db.collection.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5834bd23ba41f1f22e600c7d"), "items" : {$not : {$elemMatch : categories[0]}}}, {$addToSet : {'items' : {$each : categories }}});
```